# How to show literal HTML script in a web page?

Tags: html

I have some HTML script that I would like to make it display in a web page like the code option here:

```
<a href="#">test</a>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to HTML-escape your text, as you can easily tell if you look at the HTML source of this very page:

```
<div class="post-text">
    <p>I have some HTML that I would like to make it appear like the code option here</p>

    <pre><code>&lt;a href="#"&gt;test&lt;/a&gt;
    </code></pre>

    <p>How can I do it?</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

You'll need to encode the angle brackets etc in order to show this on the page.

You can do this manually in html as:

```
&lt;a href="#"&gt;test&lt;/a&gt;
```

Where:

```
&lt; = <

&gt; = >
```

For other characters here's a table of character codes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: "HTML codes" and "HTML number" must be the most ignorant way of labelling the table -- what a terrible website. Even [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) makes a better reference...

Comment: Thanks Kerrek. I've replaced the link with this better reference.